# How to secure my front Angular application with an OAuth and a BAck java?

Tags: java, angular, oauth

I have a Java11 springboot Angular13 application with lib angular-oauth2-oidc, and I have open id connect authentication.

So, in front, I have the token and I add it my requests, and in Back I have security the application, but I don't have a log while I'm in level TRACE, but I don't have no log on front calls.

So I don't know what is blocking the communication between the front and the java backend.

Communication back-OAuth ok, and front-OAuth ok

OAuth2 mode is

request front Implicit Grant.

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/domains/sync
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer [object Object]
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36


Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/domains/sync
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: XXX
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Angular

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: InitialAuthService) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const  token = this.authService.decodedAccessToken? this.authService.decodedAccessToken:null;
    if (typeof token != 'undefined' && token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ` + token,
        },
      });
      console.debug("new request =>");
      console.debug(request);
    }
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        if (err.status === 401) {
        }
        const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Java

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
                        exchanges
                                .pathMatchers("/", "/error").permitAll()
                                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                );
        return http.build();
    }
}
@Controller
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String user(Model model,
                       @AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser oidcUser) {
        model.addAttribute("userName", oidcUser.getName());
        model.addAttribute("audience", oidcUser.getAudience());
        return "user";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

after change

angular

```js
imports: [OAuthModule.forRoot({
    resourceServer: {
        allowedUrls: [environment.url],
        sendAccessToken: true
    }
})],
```

Java

```java
@Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        http
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
                        exchanges
                                .pathMatchers("/", "/error").permitAll()
                                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                );
        return http.build();
```

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Authorization: Bearer 4NzAsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Ijg1OTE1NGRkZmFlNzQyMDdiN2ZmODc0ODc5ZjVhYTNjLU1TU0FkbWl...
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.50
```

I have no role, scope: "openid"

I just want my services to be authenticated.

I added the following options

I have no control over the oauth2 server, because i just consume it and many other application use it

I get this nothing happens level log debug i try example and example and my car

`@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true) @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true, jsr250Enabled=true, prePostEnabled=true)`

```
************************************************************

Request received for OPTIONS '/api/domains/':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@18b486f4

servletPath:/api/domains/
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
accept: */*
access-control-request-method: POST
access-control-request-headers: authorization,content-type
origin: XXX
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
sec-fetch-dest: empty
referer: http://localhost:4200/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  ChannelProcessingFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CorsFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]


************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

First, do not try to decode nor interpret access-tokens client side (in you Angular app). Just forward it in authorization header. If you need authenticated user data on the client, use ID-token (or query authorization-server user end-point)

Second, don't write OAuth2 logic yourself in your Angular app. Use a lib like [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) instead. It provides with interceptor (as the one you wrote), route guards, access-tokens refreshing (before it expires), and more.

Last, you should urgently read [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers). In OAuth2 wording, a Spring API is a "resource-server", not a "client". Configure it as follow (details in the article):

- use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` instead of `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`
- use `http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()` (or `http.oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken()` if access-tokens are not JWTs) instead of `http.oauth2Login(...)`

Comment: in front seed i alredy  use "angular-oauth2-oidc" and I hadn't seen that there was already an interceror

Comment: After changing lib to server and jwt I still don't see any call in log with nav or postman

Comment: [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) is not the same as [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client), and I have a clear preference for the 2nd. Have you solely opened [the doc](https://angular-auth-oidc-client.com/)? Because my Angular apps do send bearer tokens (and I can see it both in the browser and on the server). If using Postman, you have to go to Authorization tab of your request (or collection), setup OAuth2 and aquire a token before sending your request.

Comment: Last, you should read a bit more about OAuth2 and its OpenID extension (starting with [the article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers) I already linked), I'm not sure you master the subject enough. Also your conf still references oauth2Login. The preceding article has a complete resource-server sample and it doesn't. Follow links before commenting on an answer.

Comment: your link is dead, how to test?

Comment: Here is another one https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I use this  and work

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().cors().and().csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

But I can't do the integration tests on my APIs and on the connection

Comment: For unit and integration tests with mocked Authorization: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken